# How do I implement toast messages in Django?

Tags: jquery, django

I am trying to implement toastmessage in my django project.

I followed this link https://pypi.org/project/django-toast-messages/ and made all the files and did everything mentioned but I cannot get a toastmessage no matter what. Please Help.

Comment: your question is not clear..what error you are getting ? I recommend you use material toast - https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#snackbar-section

Comment: I am not getting any error but the toast message is nowhere to be seen;

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. For example in your `views.py`:

```
messages.success(request, 'Successfully!')
```

You can use this one in your HTML:

```
{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
      <div class="toast-header">
        <strong class="me-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
        <small>11 mins ago</small>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="toast-body">
        {{ message }}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Also you need this JavaScript:

```
{% if messages %}
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.toast').toast('show');
    });
  </script>
{% endif %}
```